# how to pass a string with spaces as argument in shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, data

Below is my code to which i'm trying to pass a 3 argument like "client name with datacenter" hostname ip

so, "client name with Datacenter" is the 1st argument
likewise hostname and ip is 2nd and 3rd argument.

is there any way i could pass the first argument as it is with spaces, as of now it's now not working as expected, because after space every word it's taking as different argument.

Actual issue is i want to pass this whole sentence as argument. "Actual Servers to be added". Is there any way i could do this? So this argument will be further used to look into a text file and search the string where the additional arguments $2 and $3 will get add.

```
#! /bin/bash

user=whoami
#file1=/home/xymon/server/bin/ghostlist.cgi
logfile=logfile1  ###Local Log file######
client="$@"
hostname=$2
ip=$3
####taking backup while editing hosts file everytime#####
#cp -pr /home/xymon/server/etc/hosts.cfg "/home/xymon/server/etc/hosts.$(date +"%Y%m%d")"
echo $ip
echo $hostname

echo "hostfile is modified @ `date`" >>$logfile
printf '%s\n' 'g/"'$client'"/+2i\' ''$ip'     '$hostname'            # testip "TRENDS:*,netstat:netstat|netstat1|netstat2|netstat3"' 'wq' | ed -s hosts
```

Comment: It's unclear how your call your script, but if you quote the first argument, it should be available as `"$1"` in your script.  Could you clarify your issue?

Comment: You say “now it's now working”. Is that a typo for “now it's ***not*** working”? … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer.

Comment: its a shell script so we are executing it by using ./script name.

Comment: @VarunDogra But the script that you show takes at least three parameters, so you can't execute it using just `./script`.  See also my first comment again.

Comment: yes correct.. i'm executing it with three arguments.

Comment: ./script-name "Actual Servers to be added" hostname ip <--- in this way.. here when i'm executing in this way. the first string "Actual Servers to be added" is causing issue. The script is not taking the whole line as argument.

Comment: It is, but you never look at `"$1"` in your code. You use `"$@"` which is _all_ arguments.

Comment: if i use $i instead of $@, it will give me same output.

Comment: printf '%s\n' 'g/"'$client'"/+2i\' ''$ip'     '$hostname'            # testip "TRENDS:*,netstat:netstat|netstat1|netstat2|netstat3"' 'wq' | ed -s hosts

Comment: here in this , $client is the string, but it's not taking whole string "title AHS - abct CBTS Linux Servers" as argument.